# Can this laser cofiguration be used to penetrate armoured bodies?

Tags: laser, power, metals

I asked the same question before but as it was stated as unclear I hope that with several corrections the question is more clear now. As the question is more theoretical than engineering I posted here. So my question is will a group of 1000 pointer lasers of single power capability of 5W positioned on a holder body that emit rays and concentrate them onto a parabolic mirror of area 0.1 m2 which consenquently sends them as a paralel aggregated beam towards the target have enough power to penetrate a metal armour 1cm thick? (Sorry for the unaccuraties in geometry calculations on the image...)
[image]

Comment: Are you asking whether the power of multiple laser beams directed on to the same target "adds up?" or are you asking whether 5kW is enough power to disable an armored vehicle?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Want to know if the thickness to be penetrated is corelated with the beam crossection so if a single 5w laser melts 1mm of metal would a wider beam melt somethig thicker...

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1000 lasers of $5\text{W}$ each collected in an area of $0.1\text{m}^2$ the total intensity is
$$1000\cdot 5\text{W}/0.1\text{m}^2=5\cdot 10^4\text{W}/\text{m}^2=I_0$$
This is the incoming intensity toward the metal, that will have a cross-section $\sigma(\nu)$ dependent on the frequency $\nu$ of radiation. If $\varrho$ is the number density of particle of your metal, and $l=1\text{cm}$ its width, you will use the Lambert-Beer law to get the *transmitted* intensity
$$I=I_0 e^{-\varrho\sigma(\nu)l}$$
You should know what metal is and what is its behaviour with a certain frequency of radiation